# SQL Server : compare all values in two tables

Tags: sql-server

How to get the following result using this two tables

```
TipoComponenteID1   TipoComponenteID2
-------------------------------------
1                   1
NULL                3
6                   NULL
8                   NULL
9                   NULL
10                  NULL
```

TipoComponenteID1

```
TipoComponenteID1
-----------------
1
6
8
9
10
```

TipoComponenteID2

```
TipoComponenteID2
-----------------
1
3
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a simple `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    TCID1 = t1.[your id column here] 
    ,TCID2 = t2.[your id column here]
FROM TipoComponenteID1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TipoComponenteID2 t2 ON t1.[your id column here] = t2.[your id column here]
```